# c++ stop asking for input on ctrl-d

Tags: c++, input, getline

I am trying to read user input until ctrl-d is hit. If I am correct, ctrl+d emits an EOF signal so I have tried checking if `cin.eof()` is true with no success.

Here is my code:

```
string input;
cout << "Which word starting which year? ";
while (getline(cin, input) && !cin.eof()) {
    cout << endl;
    ...
    cout << "Which word starting which year? ";
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So you want to read until EOF, this is easily achieved by simply using a while loop and getline:

```
std::string line; 
while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
}
```

Here using `getline`(getline returns the input stream) you get the input, if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, you break out of the while loop.

It's inportant to note that EOF is triggered different on Windows and on Linux. You can simulate EOF with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (for *nix) or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (for Windows) from command line.

Keep in mind that you might exit the loop in other conditions too - `std::getline()` could return a bad stream for some failures and you might want to consider handling those cases too.

Comment: I believe `std::endl` is superfluous here, as flushing the stream is not needed. May be it could be good old `'\n'`? endl is a source of performance problems

Comment: @Incomputable that is a premature optimization.

Comment: `std::getline()` could return a bad stream for other kinds of failure, too (but EOF is most likely if `std::cin` is connected to a terminal).

Comment: A piece of information that may help some landing on this question: getting the EOF character breaks out of the loop because it completely closes stdin for this program. Any subsequent similar loop won't be entered at all.